# LDAP query - get users in root domain from child

Tags: active-directory, ldap, subdomain

Root domain with child domain. Users in root, only Devices in child. Due to network constraints only child dc is reachable from an application. The apps need to query the users located in the root domain. Is this possible? Any special confit required?

Thx

Connection via root works

Comment: Do the DC's in the child domain act as Global Catalogs too? If so, you can connect to the child domain at port 3268 (or 3269 for SSL) and you can read any object in the AD forest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting LDAP with C#, you can use the Directory Entry class to process authentication from the lower level to the root domain.
If you specify the PATH path as Schema, you can import an account from the subdomain to the root domain, or you can override the BASE DN information you are viewing by importing the  path and using PARENT PATH.